# How to properly stack a container view on top of a table view

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, uiscrollview

I am trying to set up a viewcontroller that has a container view then right under it a TableView. I want both the container view and table view to be able to scroll up when the user is scrolling. I know it is bad practice to put a UITableView into a scroll view. So I was wondering how else to achieve this behaviour? here are the options I thought of:

1) Create a custom table view header?

2) Create a table view where the first cell is always this custom view?

Or maybe someone knows a better more elegant solution?

Here is an image of what I am trying to achieve. The top is the container view with a side scroll view inside, below it is the table view with custom format and images.

[image]

Comment: The solution is to make a header view using 
    (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section

And then make the UITableView style group so that the header doesnt float at the top of the screen.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to setup footer view for UITableView?

```
UIView *footerView = [[MyCustomView alloc] init]; // replace with your view
self.tableView.tableFooterView = footerView;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best practice is to define a custom cell as the first cell of tableview.

And use a horizontal `UIScrollView` inside `UITableView` is acceptable.

Meanwhile you can use `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` instead of `UIScrollView` to achieve a slide show component. See example of https://github.com/kirualex/KASlideShow